# JavaScript: Replace object property maintaining external references

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I'm looking for a good way to replace a property of an object while maintaining external references to the property.

```
var Foo = function(){ 
    this.value = 'foo';
    this.foo = 1;
};

var Bar = function(){ 
    this.value = 'bar';
    this.bar = 1;
};

var obj = {
    'property': new Foo()
};

var reference = obj.property;

reference.value; // foo

obj.property = new Bar();

reference.value; // still foo...
```

you can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sefzruwg/2/)

Obviously this is expected behaviour. Usually you probably don't want `reference` to be changed, but currently I do.

I came up with this function, but I’m looking for something more graceful.

```
/**
 * Replace an objects property maintaining external references
 *
 * @param {object} obj          Object to replace the property on
 * @param {string} key          Key of the property to replace
 * @param {mixed} replacement   Value to use as replacement
 * @author   Robin Cafolla
 * @date     2015-02-05
 */
function replaceProperty( obj, key, replacement ) {
    var undefined;

    for( var i in obj[key] ) {
        obj[key][ i ] = undefined;
        delete obj[key][ i ];
    }

    // Set prototype
    Object.defineProperty( obj[key], 'prototype', {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: replacement
    });
    // Set constructor 
    Object.defineProperty( obj[key], 'constructor', {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: replacement.constructor
    });
    for (var k in replacement) {
        obj[ key ][ k ] = replacement[ k ];
    }
}
```

and you can see it at work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sefzruwg/4/)

Comment: non-object values in javascript are passed by value, and not reference - overriding this behaviour might be unnecessarily hard and pointless. Why don't you just store references to the objects instead (which will be, in fact, references), and access the property always through them?

Comment: Yep, it's just objects I’m concerned with. I noticed the behaviour while building a service manager, which is creating and caching instances of objects to reduce instantiation and allow access to services without using a global registry.